# How do I change the tooltip value of my Ng2 barchart being displayed when I hover over it.?

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ng2-charts

So I push a custom object of mine in the barchart.push function in the Ng2 barchart configuration.
The config is as such :

```
barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
}
```

Now the object I push is as such

```
{
    "data": [
        "0.11750374062372501",
        "0.06322392992964167",
        "0.11750374062372501"
    ],
    "label": "Material",
    "stack": "a",
    "percent": [
        "3.872336749782771",
        "49.427494502826704",
        "3.872336749782771"
    ]
}
```

I want to keep the dataset value but on hover I want to show the percent array's individual value.
The chart version is ^4.1.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.